# Jetpackcompose 1.1.1. Modifier.align doens't exist anymore

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, modifier

I have upgrade my projet to jetpack compose 1.1.1, together with Kotlin 1.6.10 and 7.1.2 upgrade of datastudio.

From then, Android studio throws an error when trying to use `Modifier.align(..)`.
I checked the release notes of jpc, and can't find any information that align() is depreciated.
Can't understand what is wrong here
[image: error in DStudio]

without .align, the project is buidling fine, but I can no longer align a button at the botton of the screen :-(

[image]

my projet build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        compose_version = '1.1.1'
        nav_version = "2.4.1"
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.6.10'
    }
}// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.1.2' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.1.2' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.6.10' apply false
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

my Module build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
}

android {
    compileSdk 32

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.jerome.jetpackcomposecrashcourse"
        minSdk 29
        targetSdk 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion compose_version
    }
    packagingOptions {
        resources {
            excludes += '/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.material:material:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview:$compose_version"
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.3.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4:$compose_version"
    debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:$compose_version"

    // navigation
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:$nav_version"

}
```

the composable taht was fine before but now throwing error

```
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.padding
import androidx.compose.material.Button
import androidx.compose.material.ButtonDefaults
import androidx.compose.material.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp

@Composable()
fun AddAlbumButton() {
    val mainButtonColor = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(backgroundColor = Color(247, 197, 33))
    Button(
        colors = mainButtonColor,

        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(24.dp)
            .align(Alignment.BottomCenter) // <----- ERROR HERE
        ,

        onClick = {
            /*albums.add(
                Album(
                    R.drawable.booksouls,
                    "book of souls",
                    "View details",
                    Font(R.font.font_book_of_souls, weight = FontWeight.ExtraBold),
                    fontSize = 16.sp
                )
            )*/
        }
    ) {
        Text(text = "Add one")
    }
}
```

Comment: Was it working before updating?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tried your code with Jetpack Compose 1.0.1 version and it didn't work there too. You can wrap your button inside Column, Row or Box.

```
Box(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
        contentAlignment = Alignment.BottomCenter
    ) {
        Button(
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(24.dp),
            onClick = {
            }
        ) {
            Text(text = "Add one")
        }
    }
```

Comment: so stupid am I... I forgot to replicate the Box information when refactoring my code.  Sometimes the most common errors are the one you didn't pay attention to... Thks a lot !

Comment: I think, only the **Box** composable supports align modifier so that is available to use under **BoxScope** only.